# How to correctly update form, react state with axios post request?

Tags: json, reactjs, axios, jsx

I'm currently making a post request using axis but the data I pass into my form isn't being updated.

I keep receiving a 404 error.I think it might be the form info isn't being passed to the post request.

I do think my logic is correct, the only issue I can think go is how I'm accessing the address object in my state maybe or how the keys in address is accessed in the input tags.

This is how the JSON POST body should be:

```
{
    "first_name": "Craig",
    "last_name": "Williams",
    "address": {
        "line_1": "123 Mark Lane",
        "line_2": "3B",
        "city": "Brooklyn",
        "region": "NY",
        "postal": "41211"
    }
}
```

Current after the form is filled out I console log the state in onSubmit nd this is what is logged. It's incorrect, it should be more like the JSON body.

```
{first_name: "Craig", 
last_name: "Williams", 
address: "123 Mark Lane", 
line_2: "41211"}
```

Currently my code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


class App extends React.Component{
 state = {
        first_name : '',
        last_name : '',
        address : {
          line_1: '',
          line_2: '',
          city: '',
          state: '',
          zipcode: ''
        }
    }

onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const {first_name,last_name,address} = this.state;
    console.log(address)
    axios.post(`website to hit`,{first_name,last_name,address})
      .then((result) => {

        this.setState({ result.data });
      }) .catch((error)=> {
           console.log(error);
     });
  }

render() {
    const { first_name, last_name, address } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="App">
        <div className="left">
          <h1>Rocket Insurance</h1>
          <h1 className='p-left'>As interplanetary travel becomes mainstream </h1>
        </div>
        <div className="right">
        <h2>Recieve a free qoute today</h2>
         <div className="form">
         <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="first_name"
              placeholder='First Name'
              value={first_name}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="last_name"
              placeholder='Last Name'
              value={last_name}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="address"
              placeholder='Street'
              value={address['line_1']}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
              <input
              type="text"
              name="line_2"
              placeholder='Apt number'
              value={address['line_2']}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
              <input
              type="text"
              name="line_2"
              placeholder='City'
              value={address['city']}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
              <input
              type="text"
              name="line_2"
              placeholder='State'
              value={address['region']}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
              <input
              type="text"
              name="line_2"
              placeholder='zipcode'
              value={address['region']}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <button className='button-sign-in'>Log in</button>
          </form>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you try to hit API via Postman or any rest client? Does it give 404?

Comment: After a few console logs I did try postman, 200 response and I saw the data @KarthikR

Comment: Okay. Next thing would be, did you inspect in developer tools on the network request tab? That's should clearly show what request went through.

Comment: Console log your state before the post is made in your onSubmit. You will not your address is no longer and object but a flat key value pair. I fact i believe restructuring address like u are doing in onSubmit will result in an undefined

Comment: @MiDas I just logged the state and posted what is being logged, its incorrectly updating the state

Comment: @KarthikR in the network tab its returning 404

Comment: The title of this issue is off with the content of the body of this issue ). You are asking how to update state with the post response, then you ask why my post request returns an 400.

Comment: @bruce your state is actually properly updating based on your code. Will post a solution soon

Comment: @bruce. codesandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-feistel-onq5g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In should resolve your issue. Your input names were not matching the state values you were trying to change. Your handleChange handler was not designed to handle nested objects however, so i rather flattened your state and on submit, i structure the state to resemble the required object shape for post

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    line_1: "",
    line_2: "",
    city: "",
    state: "",
    zipcode: ""
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { first_name, last_name, ...address } = this.state;
    console.log({ first_name, last_name, address: { ...address } });
    // axios.post(`https://fed-challenge-api.sure.now.sh/api/v1/quotes`,{ first_name, last_name, address: { ...address } })
    //   .then((result) => {
    //     console.log("QUOTE:",result)
    //     this.setState({ result.data });
    //   }) .catch((error)=> {
    //        console.log(error);
    //  });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      first_name,
      last_name,
      zipcode,
      line_1,
      line_2,
      city,
      state
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="left">
          <h1>Rocket Insurance</h1>
          <h1 className="p-left">
            As interplanetary travel becomes mainstream, we're excited to offer
            rocket owners comprehensive coverage options to let them fly through
            space worry-free{" "}
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div className="right">
          <h2>Recieve a free qoute today</h2>
          <div className="form">
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="first_name"
                placeholder="First Name"
                value={first_name}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="last_name"
                placeholder="Last Name"
                value={last_name}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="line_1"
                placeholder="Street"
                value={line_1}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="line_2"
                placeholder="Apt number"
                value={line_2}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="city"
                placeholder="City"
                value={city}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="state"
                placeholder="State"
                value={state}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="zipcode"
                placeholder="zipcode"
                value={zipcode}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <button className="button-sign-in">Log in</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Form;
```

Comment: we organizing the state really helped and changing the handle submit. this makes more sense.

Comment: Looks like you made the form as a component by itself. this was smart in your sandbox example.